# Is there any Deep Freeze-like application for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'd like to know if there is any alternative to Deep Freeze for Linux that still under development, because I've read some things on the internet and looks like the same company which developed Deep Freeze had a Linux version of it, but the project was discontinued.

Comment: Why would you want that? Just don't allow non-root users to change system files.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I just edited the question to answer your commentary.

Comment: Hi you can try this alternative http://sourceforge.net/projects/dafturnofris-id/

Comment: Normal (out-of-the-box) "guest" users in (recent?) Ubuntu are created on-the-fly, have their home in `/tmp`, and are cleaned up after logout... isn't this sufficient?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OFRIS is an open source application that can freeze your Linux, it is like Deep Freeze in Microsoft Windows operating system.

For Ubuntu versions 9.10, 10.04 and 10.10.  To Install OFRIS, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tldm217/tahutek.net -y
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ofris-en -y
```

For Ubuntu versions 11.04, 11.10, 12.04, and  13.04.  To Install OFRIS, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

[[COPY-fileformat]](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15265986/)

```
if [ $(uname -m) == "x86_64" ]; then deb="http://goo.gl/DleLl"; else deb="http://goo.gl/V94Qs"; fi && wget -q $deb -O ofris.deb && sudo dpkg -i ofris.deb && rm ofris.deb
```

Image below shows OFRIS running on 13.04

[image]

<sup>Source:[XGeek](http://xubuntugeek.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-deep-freeze-xubuntu-with-ofris.html)</sup>

Comment: I installed this in 15.10 then i applied Freeze by pressing 3 it confirmed me system is in frozen mode. Then i rebooted, i made a file /var/tmp/myname with value, then again i rebooted but still the file is there. How is this freezing?

Comment: What do you exactly mean?  Also I need to check to see if this works on 15.10.  System freezing is reseting everything to the way it was before it was frozen.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

***Warning:** I have implemented this solution and it does work, but the merge times to get back to the snapshot can cause the boot process to take a long time if large changes were made to the system during it's last boot. During this wait period, it may appear to users that the system is hanging!*

*Also beware that anyone who has sufficient knowledge to mount the snapshot, could make changes to the "frozen" state. I have taken advantage of this possibility to update "frozen" systems, but again, this too can increase time it takes to merge (revert to) the snapshot!*

---

## LVM snapshots + cron + script = "frozen" state

I recently started digging into LVM and it occured to me that one could feasibly create a "frozen" state on a machine using LVM and it's snapshot capabilities. Of course, this method requires a system that is configured using LVM (or at least LVM on the partitions to be frozen).

**Summary:**

1. Install system on LVM partitions reserving enough space on a PV for a snapshot
2. Get the system configured the way you want it.
3. Create a cron job that runs as root at boot to merge the snapshot and create a new snapshot to replace the merged one
4. All successive reboots revert to the snapshot. All snapshots created are taken of the system in the state you created it in.
5. As an added bonus, the snapshot can be mounted and modified (provided you have root privileges) and the "frozen" state can be updated if needed.

---

**Proof of concept:** Freeze everything except for one partition from a clean install

The installation:

1. Boot from a live Ubuntu disc/USB and choose the option to "Try Ubuntu without installing." This is important for manually configuring partitions with LVM
2. When Ubuntu loads partition your disk using the tool of your choice so that it has one partition that takes up the whole space of the drive. Here's what I'm working with:

   - `/dev/sda` (size 1T)

     - `/dev/sda1` (size 1T)
3. Next in a terminal set up LVM on `/dev/sda1`. I'm going to put most of the system on a single partition, but you wouldn't have to.

   ```
   sudo pvcreate /dev/sda1
   sudo vgcreate ubuntu-vg /dev/sda1
   sudo lvcreate -n swap -L 1G ubuntu-vg
   sudo lvcreate -n unfrozen -L 10G ubuntu-vg
   sudo lvcreate -n root -l +50%free ubuntu-vg
   ```
4. Now if you were to run `sudo vgs` followed by `sudo lvs` you should be able to see that the amount of free space left in the volume group "ubuntu-vg" (VFree under vgs output) is equal to the amount of space taken by the logical volume "root" (LSize under lvs output). In my case, I have 506.44g free in ubuntu-vg and my root partition is 506.44g large. If the free space left in the volume group is equal to the the size of the partition I want to freeze, I should be able to wipe out the entire partition and still be able to recover with a reboot. Leave the rest of the free space in ubuntu-vg unused for now. We'll be using it later.
5. Now install Ubuntu using manual partitioning

   [image: screenshot]
6. When install is finished, go ahead and reboot into the newly installed system.
7. Once booted into your new system, configure it so that it is exactly the way you want it to be when the computer boots each time.

   - If you don't accidental changes to the snapshot, and you don't want the snapshot partition to show up in the menu bar...

     - `mkdir /steady`
     - Edit `/etc/fstab` by adding (this is all one line) `/dev/ubuntu-vg/steadystate    /steady ext4    defaults,ro,nofail  0   1` as the last line of the file
   - Since things like updates will get blown away with each reboot, you may want to turn them off.
   - If you have an unfrozen partition like mine at /unfrozen, don't forget to make it accessible to users who need access to it
8. Once you have the system configured exactly the way you want it, create the following script (you'll need root privileges) and save as `/root/steadystate.sh` with your favorite editor. *Note that if you changed the volume group name when setting up LVM, you'll need to update that in the script below as well.*

   ```bash
   #!/bin/bash
   LOG=/dev/kmsg

   # wait for merge in progress
   echo -n "Reverting to snapshot if present... " | tee -a $LOG
   merging=1
   while [ "$merging" == "1" ];
   do
       /usr/sbin/service lightdm stop #prevent the auto-login/login screen from loading
       [ "$(sudo lvs -a | grep steadystate)" == "" ] && merging=0
       sleep 1
   done

   # create snapshot
   echo -n "Creating new snapshot... " | tee -a $LOG
   /sbin/lvcreate -s -n steadystate -l +100%free /dev/ubuntu-vg/root

   # make sure root comes online before trying to merge
   while [ ! -e /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root];
   do
       sleep .5;
   done
   echo -n "Scheduling reset to snapshot... " | tee -a $LOG
   /sbin/lvconvert --merge /dev/ubuntu-vg/steadystate

   echo -n "Starting lightdm... " | tee -a $LOG
   /usr/sbin/service lightdm start
   ```
9. Finally run `sudo crontab -e`, select an editor and put `@reboot /bin/bash /root/steadystate.sh` at the end of the file. Save and close (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>; answer <kbd>Y</kbd> to save)
10. Reboot, and you should have a system that is frozen except for the partition mounted at /unfrozen

This works because the snapshot is created at boot time, and even though we pass the command to merge the snapshot right after that, the snapshot can't be merged while the logical volume for root is active. It therefore postpones the merge action until the next time /dev/ubuntu-vg/root is activated which is at the next reboot. This action would also be triggered if the system was booted from a live USB.

Just for kicks, I went in after a reboot and ran `sudo apt remove --purge firefox* libreoffice-* unity*` which I would not normally advise doing because it removes some useful programs and puts the system in what might be a less than desirable state!

[image: screenshot broken]

The system wouldn't even shutdown properly from the GUI. So how does one fix this? Reboot!

[image: screenshot rebooted]

Upon rebooting, everything was back in order. Firefox, LibreOffice, and Unity were all back where they belonged.

I also tried removing Linux*. This left the machine unable to boot, however, simply booting from a live Ubuntu disk seemed to make the merge take place. Restarting again left the system in its "frozen" state.

If you wanted to be able to make changes, you could (re)mount the snapshot with rw privileges and then `chroot` to it and make any changes that you want to remain permanent. This isn't flawless, but it's a proof of concept.

Answer (score 1):

By default Ubuntu and most other Unices deny regular users (students, guests) write access to system files. Only an administrator with the proper authorisation (username and key) can install software, change system settings, or delete partitions.

Regular users can, by default, only write in their home directory and the system's temporary directory. A common way to handle one-time guest sessions is to put their home directory inside the temp directory, and the temp directory in main memory.

If you want to make extra sure, mount the system partition read-only and lay an [aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) partition over it that stores changes in main memory.

Answer (score 1):

### [fsprotect](https://github.com/sharhalakis/fsprotect)

fsprotect is a set of scripts that protect existing filesystems. fsprotect is excellent for public computers like those in libraries, internet cafés, etc.

Using aufs they pack a tmpfs filesystem forcing changes to be written to the tmpfs filesystem.

The root filesystem is protected by an initramfs script. Other filesystems are protected by an init script. All protected filesystems become read-only ensuring their immutability even on power-offs.

To install fsprotect in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install fsprotect
```

The benefits of using fsprotect are:

- Filesystems are protected and no change is ever written to the disk.
- Protected filesystems are mounted read-only. This means that they aren't damaged when the computer is turned off improperly.
- It is very easy to use.
- In some cases it makes the filesystem access faster.

The drawbacks of using fsprotect are:

- Filesystem changes cannot be more than a predefined limit in bytes (set by you).
- Since tmpfs is heavily used, you need to have adequate swap space.

Comment: Install fails on Ubuntu 16.04.2. Problem is a bad reference to `touch` in an initram script. It points to `/usr/bin/touch` rather than `/bin/touch`. This can be forced to work, but even when installed, network stops working.

Comment: Network stops working could be because you are using a bad kernel or a kernel without header files. When the computer reboots wait until the manufacturer's splash screen disappears, then press the Shift key to show the GRUB boot options. From the purple GRUB screen select *Advanced options for Ubuntu* and press Enter. A new purple screen will appear showing a list of kernels. Select a different kernel and press Enter.

Comment: It's practically a new install with all updates. I tried the old kernel, and at first it booted with networking, but then I realized that fsprotect wasn't bundled in the old kernel. I updated all kernels and now I have no networking when I boot in from either kernel.

Comment: Removing the fsprotect option from grub and updating initramfs disabled fsprotect of course, and network works again. Clearly it's something in fsprotect that is breaking networking.

Answer (score 1):

### Add a Guest User to Ubuntu 22.04 +

A Guest user requires Lightdm. Lightdm was replaced by GDM in Ubuntu 16.10. It is easy to reinstall and activate the Guest Account.

- Install **lightdm**:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install lightdm
  ```
- At popup select lightdm as display manager.
- For 23.04 install **gedit**:

  ```
     sudo apt install gedit
  ```
- After installs run:

  ```
    sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
  ```
- Change: `allow-guest=true`.
- On next boot there will be a guest user, no changes will be saved during a guest user session.
- The administrator may change settings and add programs.

[Customize Guest Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession)

- I also managed to get Guest User working on a USB flash drive with Ubuntu 22.04 and prior:

[Add Guest user to Persistent flash drive](https://askubuntu.com/q/946919/43926)

Comment: I have not yet managed to get guests working with Ubuntu 23.04 Persistent USB drive.