# How to deepfreeze Ubuntu like Windows deepfreeze?

Tags: backup, security

Is there any application in Ubuntu that can do exactly what Windows DeepFreeze does? 
(for example: you are working fine but when you restart the PC it always goes back to the time when you applied deepfreeze)

Example:

When you want to un-deepfreeze you apply password, so that it can be used by anyone but only Admin can un-deepfreeze to upgrade.
[image]

Once you logged in you can then tell is it frozen mode or upgrade mode:

[image]

How can i do this in Ubuntu please?

**EDIT:**

DeepFreeze for Windows works as below:

1 - you have installed windows 8.1 pro with drivers, softwares, config, policy etc etc. you are happy with your configuration and you think its final and reliable and its stable. But now you want to allow this KIOSK to be used by Public locations

2 - Because it has to run in Public locations there are many issues. To get prevent from all the issues there is this tool call DeepFreeze. You can install it once and make everything frozen. Which allow the users to work day and night without cause any problem in the PC.

3 - When the PC is rebooted, DeepFreeze automagically restore to the position when DeepFreeze was applied.

This prevent the system to run 24/7 in a public location or in a location where you want to deploy reliable, stable release for not to expect any new surprises.

DeepFreeze provide that solution and its very easy to configure takes about 4 to 5 minutes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe precisely what this freeze should mean. Remember that we don't use Windows so we have no idea what you're talking about. What you describe sounds like a simple suspend. What else do you need?

Comment: OK - let me upgrade the EDIT Section.

Comment: Don't add an EDIT section, just edit it directly.

Comment: Why you don't use guest user? As I read it work like Deepfreeze.

Comment: Why was this marked as a duplicate? Which question is this a duplicate of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's some open source software called OFRIS that does exactly what your looking for. Check out the project page here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dafturnofris-id/

And for a little help installing check out this link:
[Is there any Deep Freeze-like application for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349678/is-there-any-deep-freeze-like-application-for-ubuntu)

And here's an alternative solution:
http://www.webupd8.org/2009/07/deep-freeze-like-software-for-ubuntu.html

Comment: We use OFRIS in the workplace and it works perfect for this kind of lockdown control.  I can definitely recommend it.