# Wubi dual boot error [Windows 7 & Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64]

Tags: 14.04, windows-7, wubi, mountpoint

**Error message**

> `BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
>   Enter 'help' for a list of built in commands.`
>
> `(initramfs) Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened. The volume may be already mounted, or another software may use it which could be identified for example by the help of the 'fuser' command.
>   mount: mounting /dev/dm-2 on /tmpmountpoint failed: No such device
>   /scripts/casper-premount/30custom-installation: line 100: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found`
>
> `Could not find the installation files /ubuntu/install/custom-installation
>   This could also happen if the file system is not clean because of an operating system crash, an interrupted boot process, an improper shutdown, or unplugging of a removable device without first unmounting or ejecting it. To fix this, simply reboot into Windows, let it fully start, log in, run 'chkdsk /r', then gracefully shut down and reboot back into Windows. After this you should you should be able to reboot again and resume the installation.`

**Logs**

```
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: === wubi 14.04 rev286 ===
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\users\uczen\appdata\local\temp\wubi-14.04-rev286.log
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="C:\\Users\\uczen\\Desktop\\linux\\wubi.exe"']
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\data
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\bin\7z.exe
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\wubi.exe
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=pl_PL
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1250
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\data\isolist.ini
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 7 Professional
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=7600
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=1
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=PL
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=Europe/Warsaw
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=uczen
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=uczen
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\uczen
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1045
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=Polish
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 245 Processor
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 933439.820313 mb free ntfs)
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 933439.820313 mb free ntfs)
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free )
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=C:\ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=Ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=68486165
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=pl
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: python locale=('pl_PL', 'cp1250')
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: locale=pl_PL.UTF-8
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4095.3671875
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Already installed, running the uninstaller...
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Running the uninstaller...
09-20 18:19 INFO   CommonBackend: This is the uninstaller running
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: __init__...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: on_init...
09-20 18:19 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\translations, languages=['pl_PL', 'pl']
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Received settings
09-20 18:19 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\translations, languages=['pl_PL', 'pl']
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running Usuwanie wpisu programu uruchomieniowego...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Could not find bcd id
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_bootini C:
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: undo_configsys Drive(C: hd 933439.820313 mb free ntfs)
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished Usuwanie wpisu programu uruchomieniowego
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running Usuwanie katalogu docelowego...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Deleting C:\ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished Usuwanie katalogu docelowego
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running Usuwanie wpisów rejestru...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished Usuwanie wpisów rejestru
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Almost finished uninstalling
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Finished uninstallation
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\wubi.exe
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\data\isolist.ini
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu Studio-i386
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=vista
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Windows 7 Professional
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=None
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=7600
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=1
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=PL
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=Europe/Warsaw
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=uczen
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=uczen
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Users\uczen
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1045
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=Polish
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 245 Processor
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=vista
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 933442.953125 mb free ntfs)
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 933442.953125 mb free ntfs)
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: cd 0.0 mb free )
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=68486165
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=pl
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_variant=
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total_memory_mb=4095.3671875
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching ISOs on USB devices
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CDs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Kubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Mythbuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Edubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Lubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu Studio CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Running the installer...
09-20 18:19 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\translations, languages=['pl_PL', 'pl']
09-20 18:19 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\translations, languages=['pl_PL', 'pl']
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WinuiInstallationPage: target_drive=C:, installation_size=18000MB, distro_name=Ubuntu, language=pl_PL, locale=pl_PL.UTF-8, username=uczen
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Received settings
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking whether D:\ is a valid Ubuntu CD
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:     does not contain D:\casper\filesystem.squashfs
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Searching for local ISO
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting .disk\info from C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   parsing info from str=Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS "Trusty Tahr" - Release amd64 (20140722.2)
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   parsed info={'name': 'Ubuntu', 'subversion': 'Release', 'version': '14.04.1', 'build': '20140722.2', 'codename': 'Trusty Tahr', 'arch': 'amd64'}
09-20 18:19 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Ubuntu: C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso
09-20 18:19 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\translations, languages=['pl_PL', 'pl']
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: # Running tasklist...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running select_target_dir...
09-20 18:19 INFO   WindowsBackend: Installing into C:\ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished select_target_dir
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_dir_structure...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\disks\boot\grub
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Creating dir C:\ubuntu\install\boot\grub
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_dir_structure
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running uncompress_target_dir...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_target_dir
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_uninstaller...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying uninstaller C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\wubi.exe -> C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi UninstallString C:\ubuntu\uninstall-wubi.exe
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi InstallationDir C:\ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayName Ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayIcon C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi DisplayVersion 14.04-rev286
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi Publisher Ubuntu
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi URLInfoAbout http://www.ubuntu.com
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi HelpLink http://www.ubuntu.com/support
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_uninstaller
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running copy_installation_files...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\data\custom-installation -> C:\ubuntu\install\custom-installation
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\winboot -> C:\ubuntu\winboot
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Copying C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\data\images\Ubuntu.ico -> C:\ubuntu\Ubuntu.ico
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished copy_installation_files
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running get_iso...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Trying to use ISO C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: New task check_iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running check_iso...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Distro:   checking Ubuntu ISO C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso
09-20 18:19 INFO   Distro: Found a valid iso for Ubuntu: C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_metalink
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_metalink...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
09-20 18:19 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.metalink err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  downloader: downloading http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink > C:\ubuntu\install
09-20 18:19 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot download metalink file2 http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/trusty-desktop-amd64.metalink err=[Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
09-20 18:19 ERROR  CommonBackend: ERROR: the metalink file is not available, cannot check the md5 for C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso, ignoring
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: New task copy_file
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Copying C:\Users\uczen\Desktop\linux\Triumfalna-Turkawka-14.04.1PL-DVD-amd64.iso > C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running copy_file...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished copy_file
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished get_iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Extracting files from ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting md5sum.txt from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting casper\vmlinuz.efi from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend:   extracting casper\initrd.lz from C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Checking kernel, initrd and md5sums
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   checking C:\ubuntu\install\boot\vmlinuz.efi
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   C:\ubuntu\install\boot\vmlinuz.efi md5 = 2902c6e94b680dc5a068543b716118ca == 2902c6e94b680dc5a068543b716118ca
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   checking C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   C:\ubuntu\install\boot\initrd.lz md5 = 8c51b6fbad7a4cd0c9756a129a6d058a == 8c51b6fbad7a4cd0c9756a129a6d058a
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished extract_kernel
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running choose_disk_sizes...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: total size=18000
  root=17744
  swap=256
  home=0
  usr=0
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished choose_disk_sizes
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_preseed...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_preseed
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running modify_bootloader...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: New task modify_bcd
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running modify_bcd...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: modify_bcd Drive(C: hd 933442.953125 mb free ntfs)
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  registry: Setting registry key -2147483646 Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi VistaBootDrive {cc70e987-7f3c-11e6-82f3-edcbbc3288a4}
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished modify_bcd
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished modify_bootloader
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running modify_grub_configuration...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished modify_grub_configuration
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running create_virtual_disks...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Virtualdisk:  Creating virtual disk C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk of 17744MB
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  Virtualdisk:  Creating virtual disk C:\ubuntu\disks\swap.disk of 256MB
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished create_virtual_disks
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running uncompress_files...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: compact C:\ubuntu\install\boot /U /A /F
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: compact C:\ubuntu\install\boot\*.* /U /A /F
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished uncompress_files
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running eject_cd...
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished eject_cd
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Almost finished installing
09-20 18:19 INFO   WinuiPage: appname=wubi, localedir=C:\Users\uczen\AppData\Local\Temp\pyl5A7E.tmp\translations, languages=['pl_PL', 'pl']
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: Finished installation
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  root: application.quit
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.quit
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  WindowsFrontend: frontend.on_quit
09-20 18:19 DEBUG  root: application.on_quit
09-20 18:19 INFO   root: sys.exit
```

So I can't run and Install Ubuntu.

Comment: Do NOT use WUBI, it has been discontinued a long time ago and it was never intended for a real dual-boot.

Comment: so ..? What i can do?

Comment: You can and should learn how to manage partitions and install operating systems for a start. You need to consider the hardware first, traditional BIOS or UEFI, whether or not the target drive is GTP or not, as the strategies vary. Then you need to know how the original OS you want to dual boot with was installed (UEFI or BIOS) so you can install the second OS in the same way. Before installing you need to make room for the second OS and, again, strategies vary.

Comment: Is hibernation disabled on Windows 7? see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/920730

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is not supported on Ubuntu 14.04; it has a whole host of problems, doesn't work with EFI, and is for the most part obsolete and not updated. Do not use Wubi, and instead do a true dual boot.

Also the mountpoint of `/dev/dm-2` should be `/tmp/mountpoint` instead of `/tmpmountpoint` The mountpoint may be important depending on what you are trying to do with this operating system. Further information explaining what you are trying to do may be required. Read the comments for suggestions about this.

Comment: we have windows 7 MBR    no EFI

Comment: Questions about unofficial Ubuntu remixes are off-topic at Ask Ubuntu. I have to recommend that you start over again, and download an officially supported version of Ubuntu from the official Ubuntu website. The latest version, Ubuntu 16.04, will do. And Wubi will make a mess again, so I recommend a Windows 7/Ubuntu 16.04 dual boot instead. Backup your data from Windows 7 before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: I also added an [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/349678/is-there-any-deep-freeze-like-application-for-ubuntu/827525#827525) to a question similar to "Time Freeze in linux" so that there is at least one answer to that question that is not obsolete. I'm linking to that answer here so that you'll know that there is an application in Ubuntu that does what you seem to be trying to do with your /tmp directory automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Wubi, it is no longer supported.

Please download an ISO of your preferred Ubuntu variant (such as Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit), get a flash drive, and use Rufus on Windows or `dd` on Linux to create a bootable flash drive. Boot it and install the OS properly with the installation wizard. The installer should be able to detect your Windows installation still, but you'll need to wipe the previous (failed?) Ubuntu installation.