# Add Guest user to Persistent flash drive

Tags: usb, guest-session, persistence

Persistent flash drives made using the leading boot drive creators such as mkusb, Unetbootin, Rufus, YUMI, etc do not come with a Guest user, as does a normal desktop install or Full install to pendrive.

It is possible to log into a flash drive using `Try Ubuntu`, which will also permit a temporary session, however there is too much privilege with a `try Ubuntu` session, such as being able to format the internal drives.

I would like to add a Guest user that is exactly the same as the Guest user in a Full install, No power to do anything destructive and a full cleansing of the Guest account after every use.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson: Ubuntu 16.04.3, Persistent install per mkusb.

Comment: Maybe you can configure LightDM to [autologin to the guest session](https://askubuntu.com/q/95405).

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson: I think lightdm is part of a read only file system on a persistent drive, iso9660 with mkusb and filesystem.squashfs with syslinux installers. maybe there is a way to add lightdm to casper-rw ? There is a usr/share there.

Comment: @Gunnar Hjalmarsson: I opened casper-rw/upper/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and changed allow-guest=true and now there is a guest, please submit as an answer.

Comment: Great! While I just gave a hint, you are the one who solved the problem, so I think you should submit your solution as an answer. It's perfectly fine at Ask Ubuntu to answer your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guest User accounts are controlled by **lightdm.conf**.

For a grub2 booters with persistent **casper-rw partitions**, such as mkusb:

Open **casper-rw/upper/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** and change **"allow-guest=true"**. Now there will be a Guest account.

For Syslinux booters with persistent **casper-rw files** such as UNetbootin:
First mount the casper-rw file:

```
sudo mkdir /media/casper

sudo mount -o loop casper-rw /media/casper/
```

Then edit **casper/upper/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf** and change **"allow-guest=true"**.
A guest account will be added to boot options.

**CAUTION**
A bug has been issued for Guest session 16.10 and newer: [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1663157).
It concerns not confined processes.

For 17.04 Gnome, LightDM has been replaced by GDM and GDM does not include a Guest session.

The user can install LightDM in 17.04 Gnome using `sudo apt install lightdm`
The install process will ask to remove GDM.

17.04 Gnome reports as being unconfined when in a guest session, caution applies.

Thanks to Gunnar Hjalmarsson for the hint and mc4man for the bug warning.