# Disable persistence on HDD install (public pc)

Tags: hard-drive, persistence

I've created a Ubuntu based environment for a public pc. Now I want to be able to prevent users from saving any changes (including 3rd party apication data such as office documents or browser data).

Is there a way to lock the user from making these changes, or better yet restore the system to default on shutdown.

All I can find are ways to disable persistence on a usb

Comment: Google Ubuntu **guest user**. It is a **lightdm** thing.

Comment: Attached is about adding a guest user to a Persistent drive but may offer hints for a Full install also. The guest user setup can be modified by root. https://askubuntu.com/questions/946919/add-guest-user-to-persistent-flash-drive

Answer (score 0):

### Add a Guest User to Ubuntu 18.04

- Install **lightdm**:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install lightdm
  ```
- At popup select lightdm as display manager.
- After install run:

  ```
  sudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
  ```
- Change: allow-guest=true.
- On next boot there will be a guest user, no changes will be saved during the session.
- The administrator may change settings and add programs.

[Customize Guest Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession)

Comment: Thanks for the edit, my code sample button is not working.