# Disable 'Save As' in Firefox or Chrome, using Ubuntu as a web kiosk...but can't use 'kiosk mode'?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, kiosk

I'm looking to let the users browse the web so don't want/can't use the typical --kiosk mode (running full screen) as it hides address bar, but want ability to prevent users from downloading a file like a PDF for example. An alternative I've seen recommended is permissions but since they can browse device when prompted to save file, I'd essentially have to make everything read only so they can't save anywhere?

It seems like a simple ask but can't find anyway to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk  You can achieve this by creating a custom session.  Removing a menu item from a specific application(s) is going to be more complicated: if there is not an option or an `about:config` entry then you would have to manipulate the source code of the application

Comment: Add a Guest session: It will wipe itself after every use. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120448/disable-persistence-on-hdd-install-public-pc/1120537#1120537